# Sequelize Associate: User is not associated to Appointments

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Basically I have a user model and appointment model. The two models are linked with a one-to-many relationship. The Appointment table has two columns that are associated with the user model. When ever I try to include the properties of the user table in appointment, I get the above error.

These are my model designs

Appointment Model

```
export default ({
    sequelize
}:{
    sequelize: Sequelize
}) => {
    const Appointments: ModelDefined<AppointmentsAttribute, AppointmentsCreationAttributes>  = sequelize.define('Appointments', {
        appointmentId: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        client: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'Users',
                key: 'uid'
            }
        },
        serviceProvider: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
             references: {
                model: 'Users',
                key: 'uid'
            }
        },
        
    })

    return Appointments
}
```

User Model

```
export default ({
    sequelize
}: {
    sequelize: Sequelize
}) => {
    const User: ModelDefined<UserAttribute, UserCreationAttributes> = sequelize.define('User', {
        uid: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique:true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        firstname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        lastname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
       
    }
    })
    return User

}
```

I have associated the user and appointment models with

```
        Users.hasMany(Appointments);
```

The code that I am trying to use to fetch the appointment data and include the corresponding user value is

```
db.appointment.findAll({
                where: {
                    client: this.uid
                },

                include: 'Users'
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize always use associations for models whose association method was called. i.e. if you call `Model1.hasMany(Model2)` then you can execute queries like:

```js
Model1.findAll({
  include: [{
   model: Model2
  }]
}
```

and **NOT** vice versa like this:

```js
Model2.findAll({
  include: [{
   model: Model1
  }]
}
```

If you wish to request `appointment` with `users` as an associated model then you need to add a reversed association from `Appointments` to `Users` like this:

```js
Users.hasMany(Appointments);
Appointments.belongsTo(Users);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to define the association properly. You have already defined association from `Users` to `Appointments` as `hasMany`. You also have define it from `Appointments` to `Users` like this:

```
Appointments.belongsTo(Users);
```